# Can't get previous UITextField with UIResponder

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement form on iOS using Swift. Im using `UITableViewController` that each cell contains `UITextField`. I gave to each `UITextField` tag by their order, and want to navigate forward and backward using tool bar buttons.

I use this code, and the `NextButton` function is working great, but for some reason, the `PrevButton` is not.

```
func NextButton(){
    let nextTag = (editedCell?.TextFieldView.tag)! + 1
    if let nextResponder = view.viewWithTag(nextTag) as UIResponder! {
        nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        editedCell?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}

func PrevButton(){
    let prevTag = (editedCell?.TextFieldView.tag)! - 1
    if let nextResponder = view.viewWithTag(prevTag) as UIResponder! {
        nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        editedCell?.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

By 'not working' I mean nothing happens, and I am staying in the current text field and the keyboard still appearing.
I tried to debug it and the function indeed enter to the `nextResponder.becomeFirstResponder()` part, but nothing really happens :(

Hope for some help... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this in my code. get the indexPath of the table row in which your current text field is. Let this be i. Next grab the indexPath 'i+1' and get the respective tableviewcell. And then do cell.viewWithtag(nextTag) to grab the next textfield and call becomeFirstResponder on that.

Comment: same result as before :/